# Resolving linear equations with parameters

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, sympy

Good evening,I'm a novice with python as well but I'd like to improve my skills by resolving daily problems. Today's task is to create a python program that can calculate a linear application such as :

```
50x1    - 15x2  - 25x3  + 48x4  =   22         
- 13x1  - 4x2   + 9x3   - 4x4   =   -25        
- 14x1  + 38x2  - 26x3  - 32x4  =   -8*u-38         
29x1    - 13x2  - 4x3   + 26x4  =   41
```

Typically I would resolve that by:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[50,-15,-25,48],[-13,-4,9,-4],[-14,38,26,-32],[29,-13,-4,26]])
b = np.array([22,-25,-8*u-38,41])

print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
```

That'd throw an error due to the letter "u" in the array B, how can I make it work ? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can get the best answer possible when you have more equations than unknowns.  Linear regression will give an answer that minimizes the mean squared error for all points.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve for 4 unknowns with only 3 equations. My only possible advice would be to drop the `u`.

#### Edit

In general, linear system solvers like `np.linalg.solve` typically conform to the same rigid convention: the first input value should be a matrix of the coefficients of your `x`s, and the second input value should be a vector of constant values that represent the left-hand side of the individual equations. If your system isn't like this you'll have to first refactor it by hand so that it meets the standard convention. Otherwise, you'll have to look into using a more flexible solving system, such as [`solveset` in Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html).

Here's how to solve your system of equations in terms of `u` using Sympy:

```
import sympy as sym

x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 = sym.symbols('x_:4')
u = sym.symbols('u')

lhs = [
    50*x_0 - 15*x_1 - 25*x_2 + 48*x_3,
    -13*x_0 - 4*x_1 + 9*x_2 - 4*x_3,
    -14*x_0 + 38*x_1 + 26*x_2 - 32*x_3,
    29*x_0 - 13*x_1 - 4*x_2 + 26*x_3
]
rhs = [22,-25,-8*u-38,41]

eqs = [l - r for l,r in zip(lhs, rhs)]
sym.nonlinsolve(eqs, [*xs])
```

Output:

```
{((1572*u + 176197)/34925, -4*(2341*u + 37266)/34925, -204*(u + 1)/1397, -2*(722*u + 21677)/6985)}
```

Comment: I've just edited my post with the correct values from my task. By hand, I can make it happen, it's just that Im having difficulties understanding how would that work in code ?

Comment: I've just rered your edits which I find very helpful, thank you for which. I suppose I'll try to figure something out using solveset. Thank you very much.

Comment: If what you're actually trying to do is to find solutions in terms of `u`, then Sympy will be a good fit.

Comment: That is exactly what Im trying to do. For what value of 'u', would the system have 1 solution exact or infinite solutions ? That's what I'm trying to figure out, can you elaborate on how exactly to make it happen using Sympy ? Thanks again for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your equation as a function of u, in the simplest case:

```
a = np.array([[50,-15,-25,48],[-13,-4,9,-4],[-14,38,26,-32],[29,-13,-4,26]])

def solve(u):
    b = np.array([22,-25,-8*u-38,41])
    return np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

The fact that your `u` is not in the matrix means that the system does not have one, many or none solutions for different `u` values. You can see that using the determinant (`np.linalg.det(a)`).